# How to debug, watch variable Free Pascal by Command Prompt?

Tags: debugging, ide, command-prompt, freepascal

I want to debug Free Pascal but don't want to use ide. Can I use Command Prompt in Windows? Help me, please! Thanks!

Comment: 1.http://wiki.freepascal.org/GDB_Debugger_Tips         2.http://wiki.freepascal.org/Command_line_parameters_and_environment_variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can run gdb from the console:

launch gdb with the application exename

> `<path to>`gdb.exe `<path to>`myApplication.exe

type the command to let gdb start your application

> run

then [**have fun with gdb internal commands**](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html) to set breakpoints, display the registers content, etc